# Iframe on Iphone not resizing

Tags: html, iframe, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive

I am using Bootstrap. Content in Iframe scales perfectly in desktop browsers. Viewing content on Iphone in portrait mode cuts off content of Iframe. Turning to landscape, the iframe looks fine.

http://codepen.io/stevewojcik/pen/RoWJeM

```
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 text-center">
        <iframe id="myiFrame" data-src="300x250/index.html" src="about:blank"></iframe>
    </div>
```

Here is a link to my portfolio site. Click on first portfolio item to see.
http://design.thewoj.com/